# Linux analyze and monitoring log tool?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, centos, redhat, unix

I have a server using OS centos-7, but sometimes my server got slow with some processes. I want to check which service or process makes the system slow. how to check the percentage of CPU, ram, or disk consumption that make the server slow. So please help me to find open source tools which can store and analyze log with long term.

Thanks!!

from the new system engineer.

Comment: Product recommendations are off topic. There is [softwarerecs.se] for such questions. But this topic has already been asked multiple times here and on [unix.se].

Answer (score 0):

You can use the command TOP

https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/top.1.html

Its a realtime monitoring tool, and comes installed in all the distros i have seen.

Comment: `top` is a good first step but will not provide all the answers. You might also check out `iostat` for disk usage, `nfsiostat` for network shares, and `netperf` for network performance. Profiling the application itself will also help if the problem is not at the system level.